# cProfile with tensorflow tf.functions

Tags: python, tensorflow

When using cProfiler with tf.function-decorated functions, it seems to show the time it takes for first building the graph only. Is there a way to also see, how much time is spent in total in these graphs?

```py
@tf.function
def test_profiler_easyToFindLabel():
    for i in range(10):
        x = tf.random.uniform((2000,2000))
        y = tf.random.uniform((2000,2000))
        costly_expression_easyToFindLabel(x,y)

@tf.function
def costly_expression_easyToFindLabel(x,y):
    z = tf.matmul(x,y)


profiler = cProfile.Profile()
profiler.enable()
test_profiler_easyToFindLabel()
profiler.disable()
stats = pstats.Stats(profiler).sort_stats('cumtime')
stats.print_stats(5)
stats.print_stats("easyToFindLabel")
```

This yields:

```
348788 function calls (323538 primitive calls) in 0.565 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 1272 to 5 due to restriction <5>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.565    0.283 C:\Users\lxx\Anaconda3\envs\new_test\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3396(run_code)
      4/2    0.000    0.000    0.565    0.283 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.565    0.565 <ipython-input-5-5fa3a402c436>:17(<module>)
     11/1    0.000    0.000    0.565    0.565 C:\Users\lxx\Anaconda3\envs\new_test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py:757(__call__)
     11/1    0.000    0.000    0.565    0.565 C:\Users\lxx\Anaconda3\envs\new_test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py:798(_call)


348788 function calls (323538 primitive calls) in 0.565 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 1272 to 2 due to restriction <'easyToFindLabel'>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.085    0.085 C:\Users\lxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmvjs_747.py:6(tf__test_profiler_easyToFindLabel)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 C:\Users\lxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5zd7ybjs.py:6(tf__costly_expression_easyToFindLabel)
```

Comment: Can you include your code and profiler data ?

Comment: Sure, just did @MohanRadhakrishnan

Comment: `Step-time graph` a graph of device step time (in milliseconds) over all the steps sampled. Take a look at [Tensorflow profile](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler#overview_page) example. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @TFer. Am I missing something or does it not seem to show the time at a function level?

Comment: Hi @leodreieck, It does not provide information on the time taken by individual functions. Thank you.